# Distributed Cache service will not start

Tags: sharepoint, caching, service, distributed, sharepoint-2013

I've set up a dev environment for SharePoint 2013. I have created a two-server vm setup with SQL on one and wfe and app on another. I get a message from the SharePoint Health Analyzer saying that the Distributed Cache service is off. I go to start it, but get an error saying  cacheHostInfo is null. Can't find anything on Google that can help me with this. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -2):

I got same error with you and here's how i fixed it

http://rakasatria.wordpress.com/2013/02/04/sharepoint-2013-spdistributedcacheserviceinstance-cachehostinfo-is-null/

Hope can help you !!

Regards

Raka

Comment: Could you please post your solution in the answer just in case your(?) blog ever goes offline?

Comment: his blog went offline